# How do I set up a Sestos D1S temperature controller with an NTC temperature sensor probe -40-120C

Tags: boil

I have not succed to configurated my SESTOS digital PID with an temperature sensor probe working between -40°C to + 120°C.
I put CtrL to 3 ( PID ) SN to 20 ( cu50 matching my sensor ) and Op1 to 2 ( Al1 actived )
All the others parameneter I left the factory setting.

When I escape from the setting the red display show a wrong temperature ( arroung 50° when we have 20°C ambient. I try with a PT100 sensor normally SN set at 21; it is also not working ( AT green display and RED display are blinking.
Please, could you give me a good setting for SESTOS digital PID for my application:  I used it for an water boiler to regulated the temperature between 10° to 70°C.
thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I just hooked up my Sestos D1s for the first time using a 2-wire PT100 sensor, and I saw a similar issue with a blinking display showing an error message. I researched a bit and found that for a 2-wire PT100 sensor connected to pole 3 and 4, there must also be a connection made between pole 4 and 5! So I just wired one sensor cable to both 4 and 5, and it now works correctly. Hope this helps you!

regards,
Andrej

Answer (score 0):

http://www.sestos-hk.com/english/download/d1s-en.pdf the schematic looks like their are two configurations.

Two wire prob connected to 3 and 4, with 4 And 5 jumpered.
http://www.lindens.nu/projects/sous-vide/pic/wires.jpg

Or two wire prob connected to 3 and 5 in which it needs a external power or maybe a jumper on 3 and 4 to provide baseline power for auto calibration. Very poor documentation.
[image]